# css menu issue, parent items width spans the sub items total width

Tags: css, joomla, menu

Ive created a menu but am now stuck on how to stop the parent items width spanning the subitems.

Im sure its something wrong with my CSS and not joomla, could someone take a look please? Ive exhausted firbug trying to rectify this!

http://www.adamtoms.co.uk/login

To clarify, when you click the "login" menu item I would like it to stay its original size rather than stretching to the width of the sub items.

Many Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Add below css to fix it
<style type="text/css">
#nav ul li{
    display:inline-block;
}
#nav ul li > ul{
    width:315px;
    position:absolute;
    right:-4px;
    top:70px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: thank you so much! worked great, the submenus have got some spacing between the parent menu. would you mind explaining why this is?

Comment: reduce the top position as per your need. I gave top:70px;